# CSS word-break does not work correctly in Microsoft edge

Tags: html, css, layout, microsoft-edge

It has come to my attention that in Microsoft Edge there is a problem with some css attributes, such as :

```
word-break: break-word;
```

Is there a way of fixing this or is there a way around this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`word-break: break-word` is deprecated, and not supported by MS Edge or MS IE. See [mozilla documentation about this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break).

`word-break` *is* supported by MS Edge and MS IE [Here is a list](http://caniuse.com/#feat=word-break) of supported browsers.

Valid MS Edge and MS IE `word-break` properties are:

```
word-break: normal|break-all|keep-all|initial|inherit|unset;
```

---

Alternatively mozilla documentation specifies that [`overflow-wrap: break-word;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) acts the way that you want `word-break: break-word` to function.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really needed this help. I would rate your answer but I don't a high enough reputation too...

Comment: Don't forget to validate your CSS. You may want to recommend that in the answer because a good validator would have found the problem right away and explained the `break-word` value.

Comment: I had to use this technique: <pre style="white-space: pre-wrap"><span class="wordwrap">REALLYLONGCONTENTONEWORDONLY</span></pre> ...then in my CSS I used the word-wrap: break-word; and white-space: pre-line; (to get IE Edge working properly). NOTE: I use word-wrap NOT word-break here.

Comment: This isn't true anymore. `word-break: break-word;` is valid CSS but it's only supported in Webkit at the moment. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break#Specifications

Answer (score 10):

An alternative solution is to make use of the `word-wrap` property which IMHO behaves more 'intelligently' - meaning the word break will only be applied when the word is too long to fit into a line width, and won't be applied to words that can simply be moved in whole to the next line.

CSS:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

The `word-wrap` property is supported by most browsers and as of today I can certainly confirm it works in Microsoft Edge, IE11, Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari.

Note, `word-wrap` has now been renamed to `overflow-wrap`, with `word-wrap` now being an alternative name for that property, however `overflow-wrap` is not understood by Microsoft Edge so stick with using `word-wrap` for cross-browser compatability.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that you have to provide width for container/text in order to use `word-break: break-word` property. The only way to avoid this is to use unofficial **WebKit/Blink only** `word-wrap: break-word` property: https://caniuse.com/#search=word-break

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth mentioning, that while `word-break: break-word;` is *improper property* , it's undocumented and non-standard property value in WebKit. This makes the word wrapping behave like `word-wrap: break-word`, but works with dynamic widths.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `-ms-word-break: break-all;` 
before `word-break: break-word;`

Comment: Your answer would be much better if you would explain why it works or point to some sources that can give more insight into this topic.

Answer (score 0):

```css
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

is the way to go, it [works also for Edge](https://caniuse.com/#search=overflow-wrap) now.

Thanks @David for mentioning it!

Comment: The problem is that overflow-wrap: break-word; does not work on Firefox so you'll fix it for one browser but break it for another.

Answer (score 0):

```
word-wrap: break-word;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
```

try this

Comment: Please refrain from answering with code-only. Note that you are not only answering to the OP, but also to any future readers of the question. Thus, please edit the post to contain an explanation as to why this line of code works.

Also, please refrain from answering with "try this". A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future readers of the question.